# Cmd execution for unit test report and code coverage report

Tags: junit, code-coverage, jacoco, eclemma

We have junit based tests (maven project) and using EclEmma for code coverage. Able to get jUnit execution report and code coverage report from Eclipse. But I want to exectue unit tests from commandline and would like to get unit tests report and code coverage report. Code coverage report should show uncovered lines as well.

I was going through website (http://www.eclemma.org) and unable to find expected info.

Is there any commands available with or W/O tools?

Answer (score 0):

EclEmma is based on [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). Among [other integrations](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/integrations.html) there are [Maven plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) and [Ant tasks](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) for it. As you can see - all JaCoCo documentation can be found on the site of EclEmma that you mentioned.